# git push not working after using CloudFlare reverse proxy

Tags: git, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I recently started using [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com) (reverse proxy) with my DigitalOcean Droplet (root access server) where I had set up `git push` deployment.

Of course, `git push` no longer works and returns this error:

`ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Operation timed out`

This is most likely because `git` is trying to access a repo on CloudFlare's servers instead of my DigitalOcean server.

What is the best way to restore `git push` functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to update your remote's URL to either use the raw IP, or add a DNS A record in the CloudFlare panel like `raw.example.com` with the CloudFlare orange cloud thing disabled (so it resolves directly to your host).  Then update your git remote setting:

```
git remote set-url origin git@127.0.0.1:foo/bar.git
```

or

```
git remote set-url origin git@raw.example.com:foo/bar.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I noticed I could `ssh` without a problem into my digitalocean server and realized I was accessing like so:

`root@35.25.234.243`  (fake IP)

so I changed my `git config` to use my server's IP address instead of the domain name and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare is good; it hides your public IP.

Just put an entry in /etc/hosts file or add it manually to the local DNS server.